# Java code - Different results for same code in different OS

Tags: java

```
    char[] chars = new char[] {'\u0097'};
    String str = new String(chars);
    byte[] bytes = str.getBytes();
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(bytes));
```

When i execute this code, I get "[-62, -105]" in my ubuntu 15.10  and i get [-63, -105] in my Windows XP machine. Can anyone tell me the reason for it ?

Comment: Always specify the encoding you want when using `getBytes`. Otherwise it is environment-dependent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`String.getBytes()` uses the default encoding to convert the string to bytes.

Apparently the default encoding is different on your machines.

Test this by printing

```
System.getProperty("file.encoding");
```